# Role based access to users

Tags: sql-server

Basically I want to achieve something along on the lines of Identity and Access Management on SQL Server Management Studio 2017.

How do I map the users+roles created on SQL Server Management Studio to the users on my application?

I want the users on my application to have user roles, permissions and access rights(defined on the management studio) imposed on them as they navigate through the application.

Comment: The application wouldn't know about the roles specifically. How do you want the roles to be imposed?  The users would only have access to the objects that you gave permissions to by default - your question is unclear.  Do you mean how do you use a user created in SQL Server with your application?  If so you would need a connection string, but again not sure if this answers the question or not.

Comment: It sounds like you want to manage application permissions via database roles. I would recommend against this. First, users will access your application which will access your database via a service account. Your users will not access your database directly so to manage application permissions via SQL Server you would need to query SQL permissions and map them to application permissions. Secondly, this would eliminate your ability to manage these as the 2 distinct entities that they are.

Comment: This question is too broad to be definitively answered.

Comment: application and SSMS and database are three different things.

Comment: Basically I want to achieve something along on the lines of Identity and Access Management on SQL Server Management Studio 2017. Maybe I can't articulate it well but I want to give users certain permissions and when they access the data through my application, I want the permissions to be imposed on the users.